# UIViewPropertyAnimator doesn’t work as expected

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewpropertyanimator

I am trying to animate a UIView and an imageView when the user taps on the UIView. here is my code:

```
// When the user taps on the featured story image view
@objc func feturedStoryTapped() {

    /*featuredStoryView.layer.zPosition = 1

    // Hide the necessary elements
    self.featuredTitle.isHidden = true
    self.bookTitle.isHidden = true
    self.authorName.isHidden = true

    // Unhide the necessary elements
    self.exitButton.isHidden = false*/

    let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.9, dampingRatio: 0.4, animations: {

        self.featuredStoryView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
        self.bookCover.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 75, width: 250, height: 280)

    })

    animator.startAnimation()

}
```

**Expected behaviour:**
When I tap on the UIView once, the view should take up the whole screen and the imageView should shrink a little.

**Problem**
The problem is that when I tap on the view once, the view takes up the whole screen but the imageView doesn't shrink, it only shrinks when I tap for the second time.

I want both the tasks to execute when I tap on the view once. I will add a GIF to aid understanding.

[image: GIF]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiexd it, just add `view.layoutIfNeeded()` between the two lines of code inside the property animator.

```
// When the user taps on the featured story image view
    @objc func feturedStoryTapped() {

    /*featuredStoryView.layer.zPosition = 1

    // Hide the necessary elements
    self.featuredTitle.isHidden = true
    self.bookTitle.isHidden = true
    self.authorName.isHidden = true

    // Unhide the necessary elements
    self.exitButton.isHidden = false*/

    let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.9, dampingRatio: 0.4, animations: {

        self.featuredStoryView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
        Self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        self.bookCover.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 75, width: 250, height: 280)

    })

    animator.startAnimation()

}
```